# Using fgets in a loop to read from terminal

Tags: c, for-loop, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to read from terminal a few lines of text with fgets. The problem is it only read one line and stops. I tried flushing buffer and using getchar to absorb the newline but it still didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int count = 2;
        int len = 5;
        char str[count][len];

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
                fgets(str[i], len, stdin);
                fflush(stdin);
        }
}
```

Comment: How did you check it?  try increasing the value of `len`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined

Comment: What inputs are you giving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fflush(stdin);` is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Don't use it.

I think, your problem is that you are inputting the more `len` characters and thus the second call to `fgets()` reads in the character left by the first call.
Just increase `len` sufficiently.

You should also check the return value of `fgets()` for failure.

Comment: That's right I didn't account for the null character and the new line at the end of the string. What is the way to not store them so i can later work with the array without these characters at the end?

Comment: You'd need the null byte if you want to use it as a C-string. As for newline, you can get rid it of using `strcspn[str[i], "\n"] = 0;`.

Comment: Your 'strcspn()` suggestion needs some polish.  `str[i][strcspn(str[i], "\n")] = '\0';` is what you meant, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. I can't edit the comment now. If you leave your comment, that'd be good. Thanks!